# Фильтр по числу вхождений нескольких подстрок в MySQL

Tags: style-guide, code-style, sql, mysql

Допустим, надо выбрать из таблицы *demo* все записи, в поле *words* которых находятся многосложные (*будешь, уже, работать* и т.п.) односложные (*нет, мне, лень* и т.д.) слова. Надо  составить SQL-запрос, который выберет все многосложные слова.

Чтобы решить эту задачу, нужно посчитать количество гласных в слове. Таким образом задача сводится к подсчету подстрок (гласных букв) в словах и выборке тех слов, в которых количество найденных подстрок более 1.

Решение, навеянное [идеей подсчета вхождений подстроки](http://nostylesheets.com/2009/07/17/mysql-substr-count/) (матрёшка-стайл):

```
SELECT words
  FROM demo
 WHERE LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
         (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(words, 'а', 1), 'е', 1), 'ё', 1), 
         'и', 1), 'о', 1), 'у', 1), 'ы', 1), 'э', 1), 'ю', 1), 'я', 1)) -
       LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
         (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(words, 'а', 1), 'е', 1), 'ё', 1),
         'и', 1), 'о', 1), 'у', 1), 'ы', 1), 'э', 1), 'ю', 1), 'я', 1), 1, '')) > 1
```

[Демо на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d279/2/0).

Пример - рабочий. Но не радует. Есть ли способ упростить решение?

P.S. Очевидный, но **неправильный** вариант, поскольку LENGTH() при работе с кириллицей возвращает черт знает что:

```
SELECT words
  FROM demo
 WHERE LENGTH(words) -
       LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
         (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(words, 'а', ''), 'е', ''), 'ё', ''), 'и', ''),
         'о', ''), 'у', ''), 'ы', ''), 'э', ''), 'ю', ''), 'я', '')) > 1
```

UPD. @Artem Ryzhov дал наводку на решение, но почему-то удалил ответ:

```
SELECT words 
  FROM demo
 WHERE words REGEXP '(у|е|ё|ы|а|о|я|и|ю).*(у|е|ё|ы|а|о|я|и|ю)'
```

Решение Артёма на [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fd66/1).

Дошлифовываем регулярку, получаем:

```
SELECT words
  FROM demo
 WHERE words REGEXP '((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){2,}'
```

[Демо на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fd66/3/0).

На мой взгляд, дальше сокращать некуда, [поэтому вот вторая задача](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244596/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mysql).

Comment: регулярки (REGEXP, RLIKE) не проще использовать (хотя я и не до конца понимаю задачи)?

Comment: может стоит как-то так попробовать:

    WHERE field like '%а%' or like '*е*' like '*ё*'

p.s. не в курсе правда или варинты `*е` и `е*` покрываются паттерном `*е*`

Comment: Соль задачи в том, чтобы подсчитать в MySQL вхождения НЕСКОЛЬКИХ подстрок в СТРОКУ. Конкретно в этом примере я считаю гласные буквы. А разве REGEXP|RLIKE возвращает что-то помимо 1/0?

Comment: @jmu, проверка наличия подстрок не особенно поможет - надо подсчитать вхождения подстрок.

Comment: в рабочем примере вы выбираете поле, а не количество. вам нужно выбрать записи, в которые входят подстроки или все-таки узнать их количество?  

Например, запрос вернет записи, в которых field содержит *слова* "раз" и "два":

    select field from tab where 
      field rlike '[[:<:]]раз[[:>:]]' and field rlike '[[:<:]]два[[:>:]]'

Comment: > @jmu, проверка наличия подстрок не особенно поможет - надо подсчитать вхождения подстрок.

да я понимаю, я просто думал сначала мы возвращаем те строки в которых есть вхождения (т.е. в остальных вхождений 0 а значит считать ненадо). потом эту выборку "врапаем" еще в один select, в котором делаем подсчет количества + left join строки с "0".

а вообще лучше бы написать функцию count_inclusions(field, "")

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, добавил уточнения в вопрос. В принципе, готовое решение в примере приведено, свою задачу SQL-запрос выполнил, однако на будущее хочется иметь альтернативное решение. На случай, если число подсчитываемых элементов в слове будет более 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данный запрос поможет решить данную задачу путем поиска слов, содержащих две и более гласных. Но не сможет посчитать их количество.

```
SELECT words   
  FROM demo
 WHERE words REGEXP '(у|е|ё|ы|а|о|я|и|ю).*(у|е|ё|ы|а|о|я|и|ю)'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fd66/1)