# Сортировка по количеству вхождений подстрок в MySQL

Tags: mysql, style-guide, code-style, sql, сортировка

Эта задача - продолжение [вопроса о подсчете вхождений нескольких подстрок в MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244463/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-mysql). В предыдущей задаче нашлось решение, которое не требует точного знания количества подстрок. Здесь же точное знание количества найденных подстрок необходимо.

Существует таблица *demo*, в поле *words* которой - слова. Необходимо  составить SQL-запрос, который сортирует данные по количеству слогов. Слова с равным количеством слогов должны быть отсортированы по алфавиту.

Чтобы решить эту задачу, нужно посчитать количество гласных в слове, и сделать сортировку по количеству гласных. Таким образом задача сводится к подсчету подстрок (гласных букв) в словах.

Решение, навеянное [идеей подсчета вхождений подстроки](http://nostylesheets.com/2009/07/17/mysql-substr-count/) (матрёшка-стайл):

```
SELECT words, LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
     (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(words, 'а', 1), 'е', 1), 'ё', 1), 
     'и', 1), 'о', 1), 'у', 1), 'ы', 1), 'э', 1), 'ю', 1), 'я', 1)) -
   LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
     (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(words, 'а', 1), 'е', 1), 'ё', 1),
     'и', 1), 'о', 1), 'у', 1), 'ы', 1), 'э', 1), 'ю', 1), 'я', 1), 1, '')) 
     AS syllables
FROM demo
ORDER BY syllables DESC, words ASC
```

[Демо на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5d279/20/0).

Пример - рабочий. Но не радует. Есть ли способ упростить решение?

UPD. Еще одно работающее (с ограничениями) решение. Приведено исключительно как дополнительная затравка:

```
SELECT words
CASE 
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){10}') THEN 10
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){9}') THEN 9
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){8}') THEN 8
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){7}') THEN 7
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){6}') THEN 6
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){5}') THEN 5
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){4}') THEN 4
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){3}') THEN 3
  WHEN words REGEXP('((а|е|ё|и|о|у|ы|э|ю|я).*){2}') THEN 2
  ELSE 1
END AS syllables
FROM demo
ORDER BY syllables DESC, words ASC
```

Comment: Не работает если в слове несколько одинаковых букв, но может натолкнет Вас на какую-то мысль))

    SELECT `words`,
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(у)', 1, 0) +
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(е)', 1, 0) +
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(ё)', 1, 0) +
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(ы)', 1, 0) +
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(а)', 1, 0) +
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(о)', 1, 0) +
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(я)', 1, 0) +
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(и)', 1, 0) +
      IF(`words` REGEXP '(ю)', 1, 0) as `sum`
    FROM `demo`
    WHERE  1
    GROUP BY `words`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fd66/22

Comment: Да, это решение меня навело на мысль с CASE и я еще думаю над вашим комментарием. Спасибо. Кстати, восстановите свой ответ к первой задаче, а? Не хочется, чтобы задача без ответа провисала.

Comment: @Denis Khvorostin, ответ восстановил. Удалил его изначально потому, что засомневался в его соответствии теме :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярки не умеют считать количество, но можно воспользоваться чем-то средним. Замена по регулярке regexp_replace. В оракле есть встроенная, например, в mysql можно написать udf:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(1000),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))

RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000); 
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(1); 
 DECLARE i INT;
 SET i = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN 
  loop_label: LOOP 
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label;  
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,1);
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,ch);
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
   END IF;
   SET i=i+1;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[Взято отсюда](http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/)

И тогда так:

```
SELECT `words`,(length(`words`)-length(regex_replace('(а|е|ё|у|ю|и|ы|о|я)','',`words`)))/length('я') as cnt
FROM `demo`
order by cnt desc
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51cb6/5)